# Automatic DC 3 line switch

Tags: switches, dc

please help me with an advice.
I need a dc switch, but the switch should work from electricity.
For example:
2 in lines and 1 out line. One in line is 9 volts and out line is 9 volts, but the second in line is about 1 or 2 volts. So the idea is if there any voltage on second in line the out is 9v, if there is nothing on second in line - the out is 0v.

Is there name for that kind of switches, what I can find all are manual switches.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for a single-pole-double-throw relay - you can activate the switch from a current i.e. the switch contact moves due to electromagnetism from a coil.

However, from your description I think you may also need a comparator circuit that "looks" at the voltage levels and activates the relay according to a rule. The rule is *your* required functionality but I'm not altogether clear as to what you want. I think you want to turn the output off when < 1V is on input #2 else just let the other voltage through?

If I'm correct you'll also need a DC power supply (or maybe the 9V can power the circuit?).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a differential amplifier to compare between a set voltage of 1v and the variable voltage that will trigger the relay on and off. The 9vdc is controlled by the relay or transistor. I suggest doing some research on Op Amps.